# Shrinking a qcow2 image when it contains an APFS filesystem

Tags: linux, kvm, qemu

I'm not having much luck re-shrinking a qcow2 image; it contains an APFS filesystem and I suspect this is the issue. Has anyone successfully done this? I did zero out the free-space as usual and have tried several methods without success.

Comment: how are you doing that "re-shrinking"?

Comment: I've tried cp with sparse, I've tried qemu-img convert -O qcow2 source.qcow2 shrunk.qcow2 and I believe at least one other method; and I did zero out the unused space on the APFS filesystem.